# Как установить иконку приложения в Linux?

Tags: linux, иконки, xfce4

Xfce4, на других DE просто не пробовал. Вроде всё сделал:

- Загрузил иконки в `/usr/share/icons/`, `/usr/share/pixmaps/`, кэши обновил
- Создал файл `.desktop` в `/usr/share/applications/`, где прописал `Icon`

Везда иконка появляется (на ярлыках, в панели, в разделе "Значки приложений" при выборе кастомной иконки и т.д.), кроме вот этого места:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что не так?

---

Вот что ставится, тут иконки в SVG, и в корне `./icons` тоже SVG лежит:

```
$ find -type d
.
./icons
./icons/hicolor
./icons/hicolor/256x256
./icons/hicolor/256x256/apps
./icons/hicolor/128x128
./icons/hicolor/128x128/apps
./icons/hicolor/16x16
./icons/hicolor/16x16/apps
./icons/hicolor/192x192
./icons/hicolor/192x192/apps
./icons/hicolor/72x72
./icons/hicolor/72x72/apps
./icons/hicolor/1024x1024
./icons/hicolor/1024x1024/apps
./icons/hicolor/32x32
./icons/hicolor/32x32/apps
./icons/hicolor/512x512
./icons/hicolor/512x512/apps
./icons/hicolor/48x48
./icons/hicolor/48x48/apps
./icons/hicolor/24x24
./icons/hicolor/24x24/apps
./icons/hicolor/96x96
./icons/hicolor/96x96/apps
./icons/hicolor/64x64
./icons/hicolor/64x64/apps
```

Comment: Вроде эта иконка задается уже из самого приложения

Comment: А вы `*.svg` или `*.png` добавляли? Если второе, то нужный размер добавили?

Comment: @0andriy, svg, дополнил вопрос.

Comment: `*.svg` насколько я понимаю кладётся в специальный каталог `scalable` (вместо конкретного размера). Вообще, посмотрите пакеты иконок в Arch Linux для Xfce, там много интересного в них.

Comment: @0andriy в scalable тоже лежит. Смотрю на свой минт, на дебиан - кто svg в размеры кладёт, кто png, и у всех работает же! Доку про DE смотрел, вроде по ней всё правильно, но что-то где-то упускаю, наверное :(